# How can we make playlist repeateable continuously in AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, avplayer

hi Friends
I am using AVPlayer but in it I want to play .mov file continuously repeatable.So I want to use seekToTime but cant get proper idea so please any one tell me how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[player currentItem]];

    - (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification{

AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object];

[p seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
}
```

Comment: Just YOu Have to Write->>  self.moviePlayer.repeatMode=YES;

Answer (score -3):

For iOS 10+ you can use [AVPlayerLooper](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlooper)

Sample from Apple documentation:

```
let asset = // AVAsset with its 'duration' property value loaded
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

// Create a new player looper with the queue player and template item
playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: queuePlayer, templateItem:playerItem)

// Begin looping playback
queuePlayer.play()
```